# Skype for Business Centralized Logging Issue

Tags: skype-for-business-2016, centralized-logging

I am trying to use logging to troubleshoot an issue with federation between Skype for Business & Cisco Jabber.  Said federation works fine for me but not for a couple of my co-workers.  When I start logging using ClsLogger.exe (Start-CsClsLogging) it starts fine.  Stopping logging works fine to.  However, whenever I try to searching the logs I get the following error in event viewer.

```
Centralized Logging Service Agent Unexpected expected exception processing a synchronous command.

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
Exception type: ArgumentNullException
Additional Data:
Source: mscorlib
Stack Tracer.Trace:
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.LogManager.ManageLogFunctions.GetNewEtlCacheFilePath(String& etlCacheFilePath)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.LogManager.ManageLogFunctions.RolloverLog(Boolean forceRollover, Boolean& rolledOver)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.LogManager.ManageLogFunctions.FlushTraceSession(List`1& clsErrorArgs)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.CommandProcessor.SynchronousCommandHandler(AgentCommand agentCommand)
Data: 0 key/value pairs
Inner Exception:

Cause: Internal error
Resolution:
Examine exception details in event to determine the resolution.
```

Details for the event show the following

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path Exception type: ArgumentNullException Additional Data: Source: mscorlib Stack Tracer.Trace: at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path) at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.LogManager.ManageLogFunctions.GetNewEtlCacheFilePath(String& etlCacheFilePath) at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.LogManager.ManageLogFunctions.RolloverLog(Boolean forceRollover, Boolean& rolledOver) at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.LogManager.ManageLogFunctions.FlushTraceSession(List`1& clsErrorArgs) at Microsoft.Rtc.ClsAgent.CommandProcessor.SynchronousCommandHandler(AgentCommand agentCommand) Data: 0 key/value pairs Inner Exception:
```

Has anyone ever see this error before and does anyone have a suggestion on what to do in order to resolve it?  Right now I'm stuck relying on the logging on the other side which may or may not actually help me in the end.